# How to correctly mock React Navigation's getParam method using Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, navigation, jestjs

I have a React Native app in which I'm trying to write some integration tests using Jest & Enzyme. My situation is as follows, I have a component which fetches a navigation param being passed to it from the previous screen using `getParam` - which works fine normally, I'm just struggling to successfully get a value in there using mock data. My code looks like this:

In my container I have this in the render method:

```
const tickets = navigation.getParam('tickets', null);
```

Then in my test I have the following:

```
const createTestProps = (testProps: Object, navProps: any = {}) =>
  ({
    navigation: {
      navigate: jest.fn(),
      getParam: jest.fn(),
      ...navProps,
    },
    ...testProps,
  } as any);

let props = createTestProps(
    {},
    {
      state: {
        // Mock navigation params
        params: {
          tickets: [
            {
              cellNumber: '123456789',
              ticketId: 'xxx',
            },
            {
              cellNumber: '123456789',
              ticketId: 'xxx',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    }
  );

const container = mount(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <TicketSummaryScreen {...props} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </MockedProvider>
  );
```

As you can see I've attempted to mock the actual navigation state, which I've checked against what's actually being used in the real component, and it's basically the same. The value for `tickets` is still undefined each time I run the test. I'm guessing it has to do with how I've mocked the `getParam` function.

Anyone have any ideas? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: does the navigation in navigation.getParam('tickets', null); come from props?

Comment: and what if in createTestProps you make getParam return something eg:
getParam: () => mockTicketsObject,

Comment: That works, only issue was createTestProps was actually in a util so I had to customize it to allow for passing a custom function in for the value you're expecting from `getParam`, was hoping to find a more generic solution

Answer (score 4):

I just successfully fixed this problem on my project. The only advantage that I had is that I had the `render` method being imported from a file I created. This is a great because all my tests can be fixed by just changing this file. I just had to merge some mocked props into the component that `render` was receiving.
Here's what it looked like before:

**`/myproject/jest/index.js`**

```
export { render } from 'react-native-testing-library'
```

**After the fix:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render as jestRender } from 'react-native-testing-library'

const navigation = {
  navigate: Function.prototype,
  setParams: Function.prototype,
  dispatch: Function.prototype,
  getParam: (param, defaultValue) => {
    return defaultValue
  },
}

export function render(Component) {
  const NewComponent = React.cloneElement(Component, { navigation })
  return jestRender(NewComponent)
}
```

This setup is great! It just saved me many refactoring hours and probably will save me more in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try returning the mock data from `getParam`

Answer (score 2):

Try bellow example code.

```
    const parameters = () => {
     return "your value"
    }
     .....
        navigation: {                
            getParam: parameters,
            ... navProps
        },
        ... testProps
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
const navState = { params: { tickets: 'Ticket1', password: 'test@1234' } }
const navigation = {
    getParam: (key, val) => navState?.params[key] ?? val,
}
```

here `navState` values will be params that you are passing.